# Queries over Subtypes

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Suppose I have the Types A and B, where B is a subtype of A, and p is a public property of A.

When building the query:

```
Query<B>.EQ(b => b.p, x)
```

I would expect that only p properties in objects of type B would be compared, but instead I found that the query built is

```
{ p: x }
```

Applied over all items (A and B) in the Collection, so there is no use of the type discriminator.
I know that the OfType() LINQ adds the type discriminator to the query, but it works only for querying, not for removal or update.

Example:

```
class A
{
   public int p;
}

class B : A
{
  public int q;
}
```

The query:

```
Collection.AsQueryable<A>().OfType<B>().where(b => p == x)
```

returns all elements of type B where p equals to x, but the command:

```
Collection.Remove(Query<B>.EQ(b => b.p, x))
```

Removes all elements of type A and B where p equals to x.
I want to remove only elements of type B.

What should I do?

Comment: what is the query that you want to have built?

Comment: A query that also checks the object type, not only the properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generics in the `MongoDB` driver exists solely for ease of use, it has no actual operational effect.

What you need to do is build your queries using both your filter and the type discriminator constraint. To accomplish that you need the type filter (which can't be generic, you need to specify the discriminator yourself) and a `QueryBuilder` to combine both filters together:

```
var builder = new QueryBuilder<B>();
Collection.Remove(builder.And(Query<B>.EQ(b => b.p, x), Query.EQ("_t", typeof(B).Name)));
```

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that. I would suggest the driver implements a special query type for this, something like Query<T>.OfType() to be used inside the builder and avoid using the "_t" property directly. Thanks!